# When banned from asking, am I notified when the ban is lifted?

Tags: support, post-ban, notifications

I have been banned from asking questions.

I think after some contribution to SO it will be lifted.

After lifting of this ban, would I get any notification or I should check every day on ask question to know state?

Comment: You'll need to check

Comment: You don't have to check *every day*.

Comment: Hint: you'll have more chances to get upvotes if you explain ***why*** [your code solves the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23864318/1287812). Check the guide [answer].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ban algorithm runs "on the fly", as explained in [this official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161021/152859):

> They're based on the current state of a given user's account on a site, **which is calculated when they try to post**

So the only way to know if the ban was lifted is try to post a question. You can do it whenever you want, as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong in trying, though if you didn't get any upvotes there's no point to try again and again.

Comment: But this means you could be notified. Just try the algorithm internally after each change of state (e.g. upvote) and send a notification if the privilege in question changes. There are a lot of notifications flowing around, one more or less would probably not make a big difference.

Comment: @Trilarion You just started in software engineering I guess?

Comment: @rene If you take 10-15 years ago as just then yes. ;)

Comment: @Trilarion of course it's possible to add such thing, technically, but I doubt the team will do it. Feel free to start a feature request asking to add such notification, now that you know such thing does not exist, but don't build your hopes too high. Sorry!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I got a ban when my rep was just 13 or 15 ,Now my rep is 62 I Still have the ban on asking question why hasn't the ban been been lifted yet ? Do I need to get another 1k rep for my ban to be lifted or it sill take more time.

Comment: @user285oo6 it is not purely based on rep. For example, rep gained from suggested edits would have less weight than rep from upvotes. The algorithm is probably based mainly on upvotes vs. downvotes. Bottom line: patience is the key. If you feel very strongly you deserve a pass, fill a form in "contact us" and submit to the team.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I'm not even sure its from upvotes.  I finally got my average question score to a positive number (albeit a fraction), and after a week of that status, I am still banned from asking questions, and that average isn't counting my answers, which are all either upvoted, accepted (but 0), or simply at 0.

Comment: @cluemein what you don't see is your deleted questions, which play a crucial role. And it's not average but rather sum of the score.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard sum is 1 including my deleted questions

Comment: @cluemein don't think so. The sum of your current undeleted questions is -4 so it's probably much lower with your deleted questions. The sum of answer score is not taken as 1:1 to cover this, so you will need much more than +4. All in all, you seem to make good efforts so if I were you I would go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/contact), choose "Other" and pledge my case.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Do you mean plead my case?

Comment: @cluemein true, explain you are question banned, show your efforts and ask for help. The team has means to indirectly lift such a ban.