# Where can you see the status of a ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

I looked everywhere in my profile but it doesn't say anything about a ban. How can I tell if a ban has been lifted without simply post spamming to see if it says I am still banned?

Comment: "The question ban is applied when a user who qualifies for it tries to ask a question. Until that point, they're like [that cat in a box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), both banned and unbanned..." ([When does the question ban get applied?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252645/165773))

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256176/2675154

Comment: Why not have an automated email spare them the grief of it all. Once a ban is lifted, a queued up email gets sent.

Comment: @Drew - This is just a guess, but I'm betting it's because the vast majority of users only use the site to ask one or two questions and then disappear. Most SO users only have 1 rep point. Most people who get question banned probably never realize it because they never try to ask again. Why invite a flood of complaints from people who were never going to post again anyway?

Comment: @BSMP let's say a handful of people work on their contributions and mods determine they should be re-instated for asking questions. The mods took that effort. It is those that ought to get an auto email. That said, I have not heard of too many re-instatements.

Comment: @Drew *It is those that ought to get an auto email.* - OK, I misunderstood. I'm pretty sure a ban being lifted is also automated though.

Comment: @Drew So... there is no "banned" status that gets overturned. Every time you post a question the system checks your question record. Doing it automatically to check and send an email to people might get expensive.  + since it is a threshold... when you get "unbanned", you are still 1 downvote (or close to) away from a ban.... so if you get a lot of votes, you'd get the email, and could STILL be banned by the time you come to the site... not the best UX in the world there...

Comment: @Patrice I am referring to a person that cannot now post a question. In that situation what you wrote above does not apply too well. How could they post?

Comment: @Drew: They don't need to post again; getting more downvotes on existing posts, or having them closed, is enough to trigger the ban.

Comment: @Drew: It would probably be a bad idea to send an email notification as people with any potential spam bot accounts would then be prompted to create a new account.

Comment: I thought we were talking about lifted bans not when you get banned. Ya'll are confusing me :p

Comment: @Drew that's what I'm saying. There is no "banned vs unbanned" status. It's a check made when you TRY to post (maybe I should have specified "try" last time?). Since I just explained how the question ban works, I don't see what you mean by "does not apply to well"....

Comment: @Patrice sorry I understand now :p  .... I am thick

Comment: @Drew happens to the best of us :p

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As a user, there is no way for you to find out other than attempting to post.

Comment: Note that the post should still be a quality post, not "post spamming".

Comment: Yeah - there's nothing worse than accidentally posting something meant for testing the waters and finding yourself blocked again from the inevitable downvotes and flags.

Comment: Well, as I already suggested in my earier post, you could find some low-traffic tag, post some dup and, if succesfull, delete it immediately.

Comment: Or just don't post at all until you're ready to post an actual question. As a wise man once - no, actually, [a handful of times now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=resource+asking+user%3A50049) - said, new users must see their ability to ask questions as a very limited, consumable resource, so they should strive to make every question they submit at all, the best it can be.

Comment: @BoltClock That is great but do we want to waste their time making this awesome question just for them to find out they can't post it as they are still banned?

Comment: @NathanOliver if you do not have a question to ask, then why would it matter to you if you could post one or not?

Comment: @Shadow It wouldn't, but if I knew I am subject to a question ban(and I wasn't sure if it was lifted), I would like to test if it is still there before I spend all of the time and effort to ask a question.

Comment: @NathanOliver Since the algorithm for bans isn't given I always assumed the reason they don't show a message earlier is because it takes into consideration the quality of the current attempt. That could all be wishful thinking but they already have checks for question quality so it wouldn't be unreasonable to do.

Comment: If you have a problem to ask a question about, then you need to solve it one way or another. Even if you can't post, the process of creating a good description of your problem is a part of the process of solving it yourself: it makes no sense to call that a "waste of time". Organizing what you know about the problem is only going to help you resolve it.